# Removing modules from vendor magento 2.3

Tags: cli, vendor, uninstall-module

I'm trying to remove a few modules located inside the vendor folder. If i remove them manually it throws an error on the frontend.

```
Warning: require(/srv/public_html/vendor/composer/../amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-with-amazon-core-module/registration.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/public_html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 70

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/srv/public_html/vendor/composer/../amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-with-amazon-core-module/registration.php' (include_path='/srv/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library:.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /srv/public_html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 70
```

Additionally, if I try to remove it using composer (which i thought all modules in vendor were composer installed) i get an error in terminal.

```
composer remove Amazon/Amazon_Core
amazon/amazon_core is not required in your composer.json and has not been removed
Package "amazon/amazon_core" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Package amasty/shopby-root is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Generating autoload files
```

The module/modules i'm trying to remove are the Amazon modules show above in the command line output.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Here's a blog post explaining how you can do it the right way: https://www.integer-net.com/removing-unused-core-modules-from-magento-2-the-right-way/

Comment: I didn't realize the amazon modules came preloaded.

Comment: you're welcome. Happy it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

You can not remove any module directly.

To remove or disable any module from Magento you need to follow some syntax.

Open file Below

```
<MagentoFolder>/app/code/etc/config.php
```

Find your Module Name and you can disable module using "0".for Enable "1".

If you remove permanently then delete entry from database and delete module from directory.

To delete module from database find below table from phpmyadmin.

```
<Database Name>/setup_module
```

Remove your module entry from 'setup_module' table.

Apply command in terminal

```
php bin/magento s:up && php bin/magento c:c
```

Your module will remove permanently.

Answer (score 0):

You can install module in magento in two ways: via composer and manual installation. If you no longer need a certain extension you may wish to uninstall it.

If you installed it manually:

- remove the folder app/code//
- drop module tables from
- database remove the config settings.

DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE 'vendor_module/%'
1
DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE 'vendor_module/%'

- remove the module _ from app/etc/config.php
- remove the module  *from table setup_module
  DELETE FROM setup_module WHERE module='*'
  1
  DELETE FROM setup_module WHERE module='_'
  If you installed it via composer:

run this in console

php bin/magento module:uninstall -r 
*1
php bin/magento module:uninstall -r*

There is a known bug that module uninstall never completes – magento2/issues/3544. The solution is to run composer update in an other console.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can uninstall module from the vendor using the command line.That command i have given below please follow them one by one.

**`php bin/magento module:status`**
**`php bin/magento module:disable <Namespace>_<ModuleName> --clear-static-content`**
**`php bin/magento module:uninstall -r <Namespace>_<ModuleName>`**
**`composer remove namespace/module-name`**
**`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`**
**`php bin/magento c:f`**